# Logstash Filter, add field from split array, if not empty

Tags: logstash, logstash-filter

I am doing a split on two fields, and assigning different array elements to new fields. However when they dont exist it ends up assinging the code to the field, e.g"%{variable}"

I assume I could do 5 if statements on the array element to see if its present before assigning it to the new field, but this seems a very messy way of doing it. Is there a better way to only assign if populated

```
split => { "HOSTALIAS" => ", " }
split => { "HOSTGROUP" => "," }

add_field => {
                    "host-group" => "%{[HOSTGROUP][0]}"
                    "ci_alias" => "%{[HOSTALIAS][0]}"
                    "blueprint-id" => "%{[HOSTALIAS][1]}"
                    "instance-id" => "%{[HOSTALIAS][2]}"
                    "vm-location" => "%{[HOSTALIAS][3]}"
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use grok filter. Here we drop failing messages but we could deal with it differently.

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => [ "HOSTALIAS", "%{WORD:ci_alias},%{WORD:blueprint-id},%{WORD:instance-id},%{WORD:vm-location}"] 
    }
    if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
        drop { }
    }
}
```